# Distinguishable objects into distinguishable boxes

Tags: permutations, combinations

How many ways are there to distribute $15$ distinguishable objects into $5$ distinguishable boxes so that the boxes have one, two, three, four, and five objects in them respectively?

> $\begin{gather} &\_\_\_ &\_\_\_ &\_\_\_ &\_\_\_ &\_\_\_ \\ &1 &2 &3 &4 &5 \end{gather}$

The lines represent the $5$ distinguishable boxes and the numbers below represent how many distinguishable objects each box must hold. I'm thinking I have $C\left(15,1\right)$ options for the first box then $C\left(14,2\right)$ for the second box, all the way to $C\left(5,5\right)$ for the fifth box. I multiply all those combinations together because of the product rule and I have no idea if that's the right answer.

Comment: Good clear correct analysis. I would say that for **each** option for the first box  there are $\dots$. Surely it is not true that you have no idea whether this is the right answer!

Comment: I don't see where you're going with that ellipsis. What do you mean that it's not true? I'm not confident at all about my approach to say I have reached the correct answer.

Comment: I just meant it should be made clearer **why** we multiply. Note that if it is not specified **which** boxes contain $1,2,\dots,5$ then we need to multiply your answer by $5!$.

Comment: Well I'm multiplying because of the product rule. I think? I would multiply by $5!$ if I wasn't restricted, because I could put them in any order such as $5,3,1,2,4$?

Comment: You know you are correct. :)

Comment: I don't think of it as a rule, more as a process. It is not clear from the wording whether who get $1,2,\dots,5$ is specified. If I had wanted to make it clear it wasn't specified, I would have said the numbers in the boxes are all different, or that some box contains $1$, some box contains $2$, and so on.

Comment: Yes, the wording is not that clear. But the use of the word "respectively" makes me think that a box $i$ must contain $i$ items, $i=1,...,5$ (assuming a correct labeling of the boxes).

Comment: Just to be clear, my approach was correct but there is an ambiguity on whether to multiply by $5!$ or not?

Comment: Yes, that would be the case.

Comment: Okay, in that case I agree with you. The use of the word "respectively" makes me think they must be in the order $1,2,3,4,5$ and only that order.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ways to put the labels $\{1,2,3,4,5\}$ on the boxes according as how many objects they contain: 5!. Then, as you correctly presumed,

$\binom{15}{1}$ ways to select an object for the one-object box;

$\binom{14}{2}$ ways to select two objects for the two-object box;

$\binom{12}{3}$ ways to select three objects for the three-object box;

$\binom{9}{4}$ ways to select four objects for the four-object box;

$\binom{5}{5}=1$ way to put the remaining five objects into the five-object box.

I think the answer is $$5!\binom{15}{1}\binom{14}{2}\binom{12}{3}\binom{9}{4}.$$

If the labels of the boxes are fixed and cannot be reassigned (i.e., according as how many objects they contain), then the term $5!$ should be suppressed.

Comment: I would say in this particular case since it used the word "respectively" there is only one way to order the boxes, which means we can leave out the multiplication of $5!$.